How to make a heatmap with linestring
I have shapefile and csv files
The shapefile has items like this:



edgeUID
osmId
geometry




325297217
305009381
LINESTRING (-46.80244 -23.91205, -46.80294 -23...



The CSV has



edge_uid
activity_type
hour
total_trip_count




325624632
Run,Walk,Hike
2019-01-31T07
5



I wanted to plot a folium map, where I would read all the linestrings from the shapefile, and show them with a color going from weakest to strongest based on the amount of trips, thus forming a kind of heat map
I managed to plot it, but the lines don't look right:
import folium
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from folium.plugins import HeatMap
from shapely.geometry import LineString
import branca.colormap as cm

# Function to read and plot shapefile and CSV data
def plot_map(shapefile_path, csv_path, output_html='map.html'):
    # Load shapefile data
    gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)
    
    # Load CSV data
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
    
    # Determine the center of the map
    center = [gdf.geometry.centroid.y.mean(), gdf.geometry.centroid.x.mean()]
    
    # Create the map
    m = folium.Map(location=center, zoom_start=12)

    # Add shapefile layer to the map using polylines with a color gradient
    colormap = cm.LinearColormap(colors=['blue', 'red'], vmin=0, vmax=gdf.shape[0], caption='Number of trips')
    for i, geom in enumerate(gdf.geometry):
        if isinstance(geom, LineString):
            folium.PolyLine(
                locations=[(coord[1], coord[0]) for coord in geom.coords],
                color=colormap(i),
                weight=3,
                opacity=0.7
            ).add_to(m)
    colormap.add_to(m)

    # Add points from the CSV as a heatmap layer
    if {'latitude', 'longitude'}.issubset(df.columns):
        heat_data = df[['latitude', 'longitude']].dropna().values.tolist()
        HeatMap(heat_data).add_to(m)
    else:
        print("The CSV file must contain 'latitude' and 'longitude' columns.")

    # Save the map as an HTML file
    m.save(output_html)
    print(f"Map saved as {output_html}")


# File paths
shapefile_path = '804387637e9638887b3bb625354623c5c83526532fac778ce885584328e169e4-1719798137525.shp'
csv_path = '804387637e9638887b3bb625354623c5c83526532fac778ce885584328e169e4-1719798137525.csv'

# Call the function to plot the map
plot_map(shapefile_path, csv_path)


Image of the map generated with the code
The problem is that it seems like it's not painting the lines right.
Explaining it better, it would be that the lines seem too big, kind of on top of each other, and the color doesn't seem right. There's a part of a straight street with red, which then changes to blue. And also the code is very slow.
